# Correct vocabulary and/or Microformats for real estate listings?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, structured-data, microformats

Given I am running a real estate rentals listing website, what would be the correct vocabulary (for use in Microdata) or Microformats for the listing pages? There is the usual data: address, photos, price, start date, possible end date, person who is renting it out, list of amenities, description etc.

Are there also Microformats/vocabularies that can be used in the listing summary page (e.g., page that displays all listings in a particular city)?

Comment: Try: http://schema.org/RealEstateAgent, I would say try other top estate agencies and see what there doing but most of the top ones lack microdata and some of the markups they use look wrong. Seems to be a confusion over the use of RealEstate over Product.

Comment: Yeah, exactly my observation. RealEstateAgent is for a local business only. But product lacks all necessary features like address etc. there is a hListing microformat, but that doesn't seem to be supported by google. This my confusion.

Comment: Google supports microformats, so, you are free to use them.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146897?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Use this format: Replace Organization with Place use `<span itemprop="thing"> Home For Sale`

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"> 
   <span itemprop="name">Beyond Window Cleaning</span> 
   Located at: div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      span itemprop="streetAddress">1231 Mallard Creek Dr.</span>,
      span itemprop="addressLocality">Aubrey</span>,<span itemprop="addressRegion">TX</span>76227.
   </div>
 Phone: span itemprop="telephone">(469) 209-9070</span>
   <a href="http://beyondwindowcleaning.com/" itemprop="url">http://beyondwindowcleaning.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: does it also allow to add properties like price, size and dates? they are important if it's about a "listing" that is for sale or rent.

Answer (score 0):

These might also be helpful for the listings:

http://schema.org/RentAction

http://schema.org/PriceSpecification

Answer (score 0):

For the actual residence, use 'Place' as the schema markup to denote address etc.

For anything *transactional*, refer to the `potentialAction` property.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
...
    <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TradeAction"> <!-- change 'TradeAction' to 'RentAction' or 'Buy Action' if applicable-->
        ...
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Name of Transaction Type" />
        <!-- If you list multiple action, here is where you'll declare them as new itemtype. -->
            <span itemprop="price">$399</span> per <span itemprop="endTime" itemscope itemtype="DateTime"><! -- dataSetInterval or whatever would be best dateTime property --></span>
    </div> <!-- end potentialAction -->
</div> <! -- end Place -->`
```

Depending on the context, your TradeAction could be set to `BuyAction`, `RentAction` or whatever can be the case.

I just would like to point out *scope* within Microdata since that is where people get tripped up. Whenever you see **expected type** in the `Schema.org` documentation, that is where you declare `itemtype="http://schame.org/ExpectedTypeName"` here.

Each type *must* have at the very least a `name` property declared, and remember - expectedType can return *a child* of that type.

i.e. If expected Type is `Local Business`, I can do `Pharmacy` if it is more specific.